# RESTful API Url Structuring

Tags: php, api, url, rest, laravel

I am stuck on how I should be structuring my URLs for a RESTful API I am developing.
My problem comes from the fact that sometimes I need to get several joined tables from a single call.

In one instance, I need to get two tables. I have a table named `courses`, and a table named `topics`. I need to get the `course_name` row and then all the topics that belong to that course.

In another instance, I need to get three tables. I need to join the `topics` to the `parts` to the `bullet_points` table

How should I refer to these in the urls?

Should it be something like this?
To get a single course:

```
courses/:course_id/
```

To get a course and it's topics:

```
courses/:course_id/topics
```

To get a topic and it's parts and it's bullet points:

```
courses/:course_id/topics/:topic_id/parts
```

I am new to this and so am wondering how I should really be approaching the structure of the urls.

Comment: You shouldn't be thinking in terms of the persistence model.  You also should likely stay away from aggregates initially...in other words "To get a course and it's topics"...should not be happening.  This would be better addressed by HATEOAS and individual resources.  Each child URL should only represent the child collections/resources.  Aside from that the URL structure itself looks sensible.

Comment: Thanks for the response Matt! I think I understand what you're saying. Is it bad to keep appending URI segments onto the URL though? Is there a max amount of segments each should contain?
Also does that mean I shouldn't really be grabbing joined tables through a single request?

Comment: I think the idea is that your resources should be seperated into nice models. Like, you should have `$list = $model->getCourseList()`, `$course = $model->getCourse($c_id)`, `$course->getTopicList()`, `$course->getTopic($t_id)`; each with a single job. That way you can make calls and get only the resources you need for that particular request.

Comment: Yeah okay. Let's say though that I need to get all of the topics of a course, how would I do that in the URL? Would I need to start using query params like this? topics/?course_id=2938

Comment: @Sneaksta Your suggested URL structure looks good.

Comment: Matt you're answer certainly helped, but @Supericy if you would like to post your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @Sneaksta in response to your question about max segments, there is no limit so long as it conceptually matches the hierarchy of the model.  There are systems that use object graph traversal style dispatch rather than explicit URL mapping or in simple terms it would also be analogous to storing files in folders on a filesystem with increasing depth.

Comment: @MattWhipple Great, that makes a lot of sense. I was playing around with some different styles of structuring last night, and I would like to use that which I have listed above, but it doesn't seem practical. The reason being, that I won't always know what the courses/:course_id is, say when I'm trying to access a specific topic or part...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your suggested URL structure is good. It also corresponds nicely to a good resource layout.

```
// courses
$list = $model->getCourseList();

// courses/c_id
$course = $model->getCourse($c_id);

    // courses/c_id/topics
    $courseTopicList = $course->getTopicList();

    // courses/c_id/topics/t_id
    $courseTopic = $course->getTopic($t_id);

        // courses/c_id/topics/t_id/parts
        $courseTopicParts = $topic->getParts();
```